# Optimize code to track player shot

Tags: optimization, algorithm, c

This code is for a simple 2D tile-based game. `x1` and `y1` are the mouse coordinates in the world. `entity->x1` and `entity->y1` is the point where the player is, the shot origin.

I would like to know how to keep the current output while simplifying the code and improving performance.

```
void shoot(Map *map, Entity *entity, int x1, int y1)
{
    float slope = (y1 - entity->y1) / (x1 - entity->x1);
    float y = entity->y1; //Weapon position
    Block *block;

    if(x1 > entity->x1){
        y += slope;
        for(float x = entity->x1 + 1; x < map->width && y < map->height && y > 0; ++x){

            //Get block at position x y. Check if found a hit
            if((block = map_block_at(map, x, y))->type != EMPTY){
                block_cause_damage(block, entity->hand_item->weapon.damage);
                return;
            }

            y += slope;
        }
    }

    else
    if(x1 < entity->x1){
        y -= slope;
        for(float x = entity->x1 - 1; x > 0 && y < map->height && y > 0; --x){

            //Get block at position x y. Check if found a hit
            if((block = map_block_at(map, x, y))->type != EMPTY){
                block_cause_damage(block, entity->hand_item->weapon.damage);
                return;
            }

            y -= slope;
        }
    }

    //When the player shoots up or down 
    else {
        slope = (y1 > entity->y1) ? 1 : - 1;
        y += slope;
        while(y < map->height && y > 0){

            //Get block at position x y. Check if found a hit
            if((block = map_block_at(map, x1, y))->type != EMPTY){
                block_cause_damage(block, entity->hand_item->weapon.damage);
                return;
            }

            y += slope;
        }
    }
}
```

The code for `Entity` and `Map`:

```
typedef struct Entity {
    Renderable renderable;
    plist_id render_id;
    Point (*get_current_position)(struct Entity *, uint32_t);
    int health, attack_damage, running, jumping;
    float x0, y0, x1, y1;
    uint32_t t0, t1;
    enum {LEFT, RIGHT} side;
    Image **texture;
    Item *hand_item;
    Backpack backpack;
} Entity;

typedef struct {
    Renderable renderable;
    plist_id render_id;
    int width, height;
    Block *blocks;
    Camera *camera;
} Map;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a little difficult to do a good review because there are so many pieces missing, but I've guessed at a number of things and I believe I can help.

Specifically, it looks like your `Map` is a rectangular grid of `Block`s and that all `x` and `y` coordinates are integers.  If so, then your `shot` routine is really doing the equivalent of drawing a line from the `entity` location to the passed `x1`,`y1` coordinates and one very efficient way to do that is to use [Bresenham's line-drawing algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060046/drawing-lines-with-bresenhams-line-algorithm).  Using a slight modification of that algorithm, since your `shot` routine seems to want to go until it either hits something or goes off the `Map`, we get a very efficient and very small routine:

```
void shoot(Map *map, Entity *entity, int x1, int y1)
{
    int sx = entity->x1 < x1 ? 1 : -1;
    int sy = entity->y1 < y1 ? 1 : -1;
    int dx = abs(x1 - entity->x1);
    int dy = abs(y1 - entity->y1);
    int err = (dx>dy ? dx : -dy)/2;
    int e2;

    x1 = entity->x1;
    y1 = entity->y1;
    Block *block;
    while (inbounds(map,x1,y1)) {
        e2 = err;
        if (e2 > -dx) {
            err -= dy;
            x1 += sx;
        }
        if (e2 < dy) {
            err += dx; 
            y1 += sy;
        }
        if((block = map_block_at(map, x1, y1))->type != EMPTY){
            block_cause_damage(block, entity->hand_item->weapon.damage);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I've assumed that you have or can easily write an `inbounds` routine that returns `true` if the passed coordinates are within the `Map`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried the code you provided and it works fine most of the time. But sometimes it gets stuck in the loop. I added another variable `get_out`, it's set to `0` on every iteration and incremented using `else` statements right after `if (e2 > -dx)` and `if (e2 < dy) `, then I check if `get_out == 2` and exit.

Answer (score 8):

I have a few remarks:

- You may have a problem with this line of code:

  ```
  float slope = (y1 - entity->y1) / (x1 - entity->x1);
  ```

  If `entity` is already at the longitude `x1`, this will cause a division by 0. Such a division is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen. A plane may crash on your house. You should check first whether `x1 == entity->x1` and handle this case properly. I see that the last `else` close of your program handles this case (`//When the player shoots up or down`), but the division by 0 appears *before* you handle it.
- I don't know whether `entity.x` and `entity.y` are `int` or `float` types. If they are `int` types, I guess that you can get rid of the `float` variables: the only thing that may need more precision than an integer is `slope`, and if `entity.x` and `entity.y` are integer types, then `slope` will contain an integer cast to a `float` (since it was initialized with an integer division).

It lacks a bit of context to provide a complete review. You should post the code of at least `Map` and `Entity` so that we don't have to assume things.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I'll post the code for `entity` and `map`.